# Size of the /boot partition too small

Tags: system

I am running 6.1 always up to date...
Boot partition accumulates the binaries for each kernel and becomes full very quickly...
I tried to find a way to increase it, but gparted doesnt allow me to reduce/shrink the size of the second partition even I do this from the install cd. After reducing this one, I should be able to move it at the end of the disk and then use the just-made free space to increase the size of the boot one right ? Is my understanding correct ? Any help will be appreciated, indeed.
Cheers. gg.

PS: similar issue has been poped up on 2016-01-30 by user3515 but answers are irrelevant..

Comment: Making the drive bigger to accommodate any ever increasing number of kernels will always be a lost cause. `sudo apt-get autoremove` should remove old kernels on any elementary version with a base of Ubuntu 14.04+